# Problema con React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

al momento de usar un onClick y pasar por parametros unos datos y escribirlos directamente en el setState si actualiza el estado, pero si intento hacer algo antes de actualizar el estado no pasa nada.

```
const handleCamSelection = (cameras, status) => {
    let cams = selectedCameras;
    console.log(cameras);
    cameras.forEach((camera) => {
      cams.push(camera);
    });
    console.log(cams);

    //HASTA AQUI BIEN

    //ACA SE BUGUEA Y NO ACTUALIZA
    setSelection(cams);
  };
```

Simplemente estoy jugando con un array y no pasa nada, pero si hago lo siguiente si se actualiza.

```
 const handleCamSelection = (cameras, status) => {
    
    setSelection(cameras);
  };
```

Que puede ser y que puedo hacer?

Agrego Componentes donde Funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde se debe plasmar la actualización del estado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el componente completo o al menos una versión minima verificable para poder reproducir el error que comentas; así como lo presentas, siempre y cuando `selectedCameras` sea un `array`, no debe haber problemas. Saludos

Comment: Actualicé el post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que es porque estas igualando el array que quieres actualizar con el array que tenía el estado anteriormente:

```
let cams = selectedCameras;
```

Entonces aunque luego modifiques cams, es un array ya referenciado al anterior y por eso cuando lo seteas no detecta que sea diferente.

Prueba a setearlo así:

```
setSelection([...cams]);
```

De este modo se genera un array nuevo con el contenido del otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias mi hermano, me ayudaste mucho